# WKWebView does not send session cookie

Tags: ios, cookies, session-cookies, wkwebview

I am embedding a WKWebView in my app. It uses a PHP session cookie to identify the user. I get the session cookie with the following call:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonobject options:0 error:&err]];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

Based on this: [Can I set the cookies to be used by a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview) I add the cookies to the document

```
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookies)
{
    NSString *javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.cookie = '%@=%@';", [cookie name], [cookie value]];
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKUserContentController *ucController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    WKProcessPool *processPool = [[WKProcessPool alloc] init];
    config.processPool = processPool;
    config.userContentController = ucController;
    [ucController addUserScript:[[WKUserScript  alloc] initWithSource:javascript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:NO]];
}
```

And I manually set the session cookie in the initial load request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *pageLoadRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[pageLoadRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[pageLoadRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[pageLoadRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookies]];
[_webView loadRequest:pageLoadRequest];
```

My problem is that AJAX requests will not contain the session cookie.

Comment: Perhaps duplicate with my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46822550/4712692)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cookies is send as `Set-Cookie` in 302 response.Try this [YWKWebView](https://github.com/luowenxing/PWKWebView/) simply in replace of your `WKWebView`.