# Javascript Injection Not working on WKWebview on Device, but is working on Simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

We need to set a cookie locally to the application that applies to our webview. We referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview/26577303). All we need is to inject a cookie. When running on the simulator everything works perfect, but when using a device the cookie fails to inject. This is the code we have so far.

```
let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
let cookieScript = WKUserScript(source: "document.cookie = 'customCookie'; domain = '.example.com'", injectionTime: .AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)

userContentController.addUserScript(cookieScript)
let webViewConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewConfig.userContentController = userContentController
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: webViewConfig)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the cookie fails to inject" -- Can you inject other Javascript (like something simpler -- a DOM addition you can see)?

Comment: You could try setting the expires date on the cookie.