# WKWebView Cookies

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm using the below mentioned approach to set cookies in a `WKWebview`:
[Can I set the cookies to be used by a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview)

But the cookies that I have set are being duplicated in the AJAX calls. I mean they are being repeated twice.

Here is the code snippet that I used:

```
NSString *strURL = DASHBOARDURL;    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];

NSMutableString *script = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *cookieString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [script appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.cookie='%@';",cookie.getCookieString]];
    [cookieString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;", cookie.getCookieString]];
}
[request setValue:cookieString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

//cookies for further AJAX calls
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
WKUserScript *cookieInScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script
                                                      injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
                                                   forMainFrameOnly:YES];
[userContentController addUserScript:cookieInScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
webViewConfig.userContentController = userContentController;

CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

wkWebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect configuration:webViewConfig];
wkWebview.navigationDelegate = self;
[wkWebview loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:wkWebview];
```

`getCookieString` is a method that returns cookie values as an `NSString`

1. Will the `WKWebView` set the cookies back to `NSHTTPCookieStorage`
   at runtime(During AJAX calls)
2. Can i control AJAX calls cookies with any delegate methods?

The following is my `getCookieString` category(`NSHTTPCookie (CookieObject)`) method

```
- (NSString *)getCookieString {

  NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@;domain=%@;expiresDate=%@;path=%@;sessionOnly=%@;isSecure=%@",
                    self.name,
                    self.value,
                    self.domain,
                    self.expiresDate,
                    self.path ?: @"/",
                    self.isSecure ? @"TRUE":@"FALSE",
                    self.sessionOnly ? @"TRUE":@"FALSE"];

  return string;
}
```

Comment: Note that "sessionOnly" and "isSecure" is in wrong order in the argument list.

Comment: Does order really matters, when you are dealing with key value pairs? Anyways i will try it and comment here..

Comment: Actuallty, it does, since you are not using key value pairs. You are concatenating a string. Therefore sessionOnly=%@;isSecure=%@ should be read in this case as sessionOnly= + self.isSecure  + ;isSecure= + self.sessionOnly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple Cookies are sent if there are more than one cookie in the cookie store whose domains (or paths) match the requested URL.

Whilst writing your `getCookieString` method you may have changed or added the `domain=` part of the string. This would cause a second valid cookie to be stored and therefor sent with your request.

Comment: Perfect Answer..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Removing `domain=` from my getCookieString method fixed the issue

```
-(NSString *)getCookieString 
 {
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@;expiresDate=%@;path=%@;sessionOnly=%@;isSecure=%@",
            self.name,
            self.value,
            self.expiresDate,
            self.path ?: @"/",
            self.isSecure ? @"TRUE":@"FALSE",
            self.sessionOnly ? @"TRUE":@"FALSE"];
   return string;
}
```