# WKWebView inject cookies from HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

I'm developing and iOS app that has a `WKWebView` and a native login screen. On the native login screen the user can login which is done with an API call that returns a JSON object and two cookies.

What I'm trying to do is that when the call was a success and the user goes to the `WKWebView` screen, they are logged in on the website that is shown as well.

The `WKWebView` is already loaded so my question is how should I handle the cookies so that the user is logged in on the `WKWebView`? 
I've read [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177750/wkwebview-injecting-cookie-header-cause-redirect-loop) but that doesn't work for me. The `WKWebView` isn't showing anything so I think it is blocked or in a loop.

**UPDATE**
I'm using multiple WKWebViews, I found out that if I do the API call, then go to one WKWebView it's working fine, I'm logged in. Probably the tricky part here is that I'm using multiple WKWebViews.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution for my cookie problem.

I had to create one global `WKProcessPool` for all my `WKWebViews` and I had to send the cookies from `HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies` with every login call I did so the cookies I got back where still connected to the `WKWebViews` and nothing was lost. Hope this helps somebody with the same problem.

Comment: i need help for handling cookies

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is supported in iOS11 in an elegant way with [WKHTTPCookieStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore). After login and getting the cookie via the JSON api, use [setCookie](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore/2882007-setcookie) to automatically login the user in the WKWebView.

WKWebView is receiving a major update in iOS11 and opening up many new interesting possibilities. There is a demo of your specific use case in the [Customized Loading in WKWebView WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/220/).

Unfortunately this will not help if you need to get this done for iOS10 or earlier.

Comment: That looks promising, but I need to support iOS 10 as well for now