# How to get cookies from WKWebView

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview

I have this WKWebView which loads a login page and what I need is the "**iPlanetDirectoryPro**" cookie (see picture bellow) that is set after a successful login (form submit). So, I'm trying to store it in order to use it in another WKWebView.. The funny thing is "sharedHTTPCookieStorage" contains the other cookies but not the "**iPlanetDirectoryPro**" one.

[image]

What I tried so far:

1. Created a shared proccess pool and used the same configuration for this first WKWebView and the one I'm trying to use "**iPlanetDirectoryPro**" on.
2. I used this delegate method **decidePolicyForNavigationResponse** to fetch cookies:

   ```
   - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler{
   NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;
   NSArray *cookies =[NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:response.URL];

   for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
       [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
   }

   decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
   }
   ```
3. Evaluating JavaScript command document.cookie on webView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

For whatever reason, WKWebView and HTTPCookieStorage aren't working perfectly together. You would need to manage the cookies yourself, for example you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32845148/3652291)