# WKWebView pick cookies from NSHTTPCookieStorage

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, nshttpcookie, wkwebviewconfiguration

Does anyone know how to set a WKWebView to pick cookies from NSHTTPCookieStorage ?

I tried injecting the cookie through WKUserScript, but it doesn't work since my page has several redirections, and every page in that redirection uses a cookie.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 11 you get `httpCookieStore` for `WKWebsiteDataStore`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore?changes=latest_minor

If you want insert cookies for iOS versions less than iOS 11 (iOS 8 onwards) following link will help

[Can I set the cookies to be used by a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not supported in the `WKWebView` so far. Many attempts (using `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, the `WKWebsiteDataStore` and evaluated `document.cookie;`) all do not work.

You can follow [this bug-report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140191) for the issue and possible patches, I hope that answers your question for now, although it doesn't solve it.

Comment: now its supported and working fine, but still you need to put some heck.

Comment: have look to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview/52490200#52490200