# How to use same cookie on different WKWebViews

Tags: swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

i need to use same configuration (cookie) on the second WebView after the user is authorized on first WebView. On simulator it's work well, but on device is not stable.

```
class auth: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate {
private var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        loadPage(urlString: link)
    }
    private func loadPage(urlString: String) {
        if let encodedURL = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
            let url = URL(string: encodedURL) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.refreshCookies()
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}

extension WKWebView {
    func refreshCookies() {
        self.configuration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every ** WKWebView** has it's own cookie space that cookie space is saved in **WKProcessPool** just make process pool object global and assign to every webview object, hope so this will work in your case.

```
    static let processPool = WKProcessPool()
```

And set your WKWebView instance every time with this process pool, other way is whenever you creating wkwebview and load implement this function.

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    // use to sync cookies
    guard let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse, let responseUrl = navigationResponse.response.url else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.webView.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
            cookies.forEach({ (cookie) in
                if cookie.name == Constant.appCodeCookie || cookie.name == Constant.rpgaCookieName || cookie.name == Constant.headerCookie , cookie.name == Constant.adIdCookie {
                    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
                }
            })
        }

    } else {
        // Fallback version
        if  let allHttpHeaders = response.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] {
            let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: allHttpHeaders, for: responseUrl)
            for cookie in cookies {
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }


    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Every time you make instance of wkwebview just get all cookies from httpcookiestorage and set in wkwebview user script for further you can check my answer here also. [Can I set the cookies to be used by a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview/52490200#52490200)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping a global cookie variable or saving to plist as mentioned above, you can set cookies in the shared HTTPCookieStorage.

To store:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    let request = navigationAction.request
    let url = request.url

    webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
         HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: nil)
    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
    return
}
```

And to retrieve and set (in a different WebView instance):

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height) 
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies ?? []
for cookie in cookies {
    config.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: nil)
}

let webView2 = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: config)
```

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cookie for each wkwebview, So keep the cookie value as global variable or save it in plist.