# Is setting up a cookie with WKWebsiteDataStore too late?

Tags: cookies, ios10, ios11, wkwebview

I need to set a cookie in a WKWebView on both iOS 10 an iOS 11. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview), I wrote different code for the 2 iOS versions, using a JavaScript script in iOS 10 and WKWebsiteDataStore in iOS 11.

While using iOS 10 I have no issue, with iOS 11 the web app sees the cookie I used in the previous session. I mean, if the first time I launch the app the cookie value is "A", the web app doesn't see the cookie; if I close the app and relaunch it with "B" as the new value of the cookie, the web app now reads "A" from the cookie. However, with the Web Inspector I see the right value of the cookie.

It seems that with the WKWebsiteDataStore the cookie is set too late; how can I solve this issue (without using the same code used in iOS 10 even in iOS 11)?

My code is:

```
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    configuration.preferences = preferences

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        if let cookie = cookie {
            let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
            dataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie) {
                configuration.websiteDataStore = dataStore
                configuration.userContentController = userContentController
                self.createAndLoadWebView(with: configuration)
            }
        }
    } else {
        if let cookie = cookie {

            let script = getJSCookiesString(for: [cookie])
            let cookieScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
            userContentController.addUserScript(cookieScript)

            configuration.userContentController = userContentController
            createAndLoadWebView(with: configuration)
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
private func createAndLoadWebView(with configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {

    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.containerView.frame, configuration: configuration)
    self.containerView.addSubview(webView)
    let req = URLRequest(url: pageUrl)
    webView.load(req)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add same cookies in Request header, i faced same problem but after add cookies in header request page load normally.