# Cookies not sent with URLRequest on WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

I am trying to send cookies with a URLRequest to a WKWebView in my phone app.  This part requires the user to be logged in, therefore I must set my cookies.  When I check safari inspection I saw that my cookies are not set and I get redirected to my login page.  Here is my code snippet.

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("cookie1=\(val1);cookie2=\(val2);", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Better check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26573137/6541007).

Comment: I have attempted Mattr's suggestion using HTTPCookieStorage to set cookies before but it did not work for me.  I decided to see if I can just directly set the cookies in the header and see if that would work at all

Comment: The thread shows more ways to set cookies than I can think of. You should better check what is special on your server side. Anyway seems I cannot be help to solve your issue. Hope you can solve it soon. Please share your experience after you solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set the cookies to be used by a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview)