# Swift - Cookie not set in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying to set a cookie in the `WKWebView`, but the web app can't read it (`document.cookie`).

I tried to set secure to false. That only works if I set it like in following code. Also tried to set the `httpOnly` attribute to false. But if I print the cookie, it has the value `YES`

```
        let cookieProps: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] = [
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: "192.168.1.2",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: "/",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: "testCookie",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: "test",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires: "2024-12-17 07:26:41 +0000",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.init(rawValue: "HttpOnly"): false,
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.init(rawValue: "secure"): false
        ]

        return HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps) ?? HTTPCookie()
```

After creating the cookie, I set it with the cookie store:

```
var configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Did you init the `WKWebView` with the `WKWebViewConfiguration`?

Comment: Yes, you mean like `WKWebView(frame: CGRect(), configuration: configuration)`

Comment: Try make webview first, after set `webview.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)` can it?

Comment: I have still the same error if I set it like that

Comment: I could solve that problem with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105615/14381148). I don't know if there are security problems with this solution, but for my case it's fine.