# Is WKWebView designed as a replacement of UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

Asking this questions as I am not sure why Apple introduced WKWebView without deprecating UIWebView. It is important to have an idea as I am programming a large code base and need to make an informed / fact based decision.

- Are there any reason for which we may have to expect both classes to co-exist in the future and none get deprecated?
- Is WKWebView purely designed for speed performance (using JIT) and will likely to serve only for certain use cases?

Current limitations of WKWebView:

https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/mobile-firefox-dev/2014-December/000993.html

[How can I retrieve a file using WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464397/how-can-i-retrieve-a-file-using-wkwebview)

Comment: "I am wondering if UIWebView will get deprecated at all in the future" That is not a programming question. It is a question about the future. And about Apple. This is Stack Overflow, not a crystal ball.

Comment: uiwebview is now deprecated

Comment: It's officially deprecated

Comment: UIWebView now is not only deprecated but Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView API

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** `UIWebView` is now deprecated and Apple is actively discouraging developers from using it.

---

There are several reasons, including security (out of process model), performance and memory management. Whether Apple would deprecate `UIWebView` is not something anyone can answer but Apple, however considering the many limitations there currently are (some partially solved in WebKit2 source repository for future iOS WK2 framework inclusion), my educated guess would be that `UIWebView` is here to stay for different needs. And considering both WebKitLegacy and WebKit2 (now renamed WebKit) frameworks reference the same implementation frameworks (WebCore, JSCore, etc.), it would not require a lot of work to keep `UIWebView` alive.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the answer. For any update on the answer please feel free to edit and notify.

Comment: Numerous crashes is a bane of UIWebView. For me migration to WKWebView solved *all* of them. That's alone a very good reason to migrate.

Comment: `UIWebView` will deprecated with iOS 11 release. :(

Comment: @Suryakant do you have any evidence of this? From their [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview?changes=latest_minor) deprecation is not mentioned? I just want to make informed decision.

Comment: @Malba See the below answer, so far only xcode is hinting about it.

Answer (score 19):

According to Xcode 9, `UIWebView` is deprecated. ‍♂️

[image: Xcode 9]

And a documentation message reads:

> Legacy UIWebView for support of older macOS platforms. Prefer using WKWebView if possible.

**Updated:** UIWebView is deprecated for real now in iOS 12.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview

Comment: Then which class we may use instead of UIWebView for IOS 12?

Comment: @CoderACJHP WKWebView

Answer (score 2):

As per [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b):

> If your app still embeds web content using the deprecated `UIWebView` API, we strongly encourage you to update to `WKWebView` as soon as possible for improved security and reliability. `WKWebView` ensures that compromised web content doesn’t affect the rest of an app by limiting web processing to the app’s web view. And it’s supported in iOS and macOS, and by Mac Catalyst.
>
> The App Store will no longer accept new apps using `UIWebView` as of April 2020 and app updates using `UIWebView` as of December 2020.