# What are the main (technical) difference when developing apps for iOS web view and Safari mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-applications

I've struggled to find any reference to web development when it comes to the difference between UIWebView and Safari mobile.

I'be been able to find difference between different browsers, but not between the native iOS web view and Safari mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure wether you speak about UIWebView or WKWebView. The last one is available since iOS 8.0 (source: [WKWebView doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKWebView)).

The performance of the old WebView component was lower than a Safari webpage because it was unable to use Nitro JavaScript engine (source: old questions on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648184/uiwebview-and-safari-comparison)).

However, the performance of UIWebView/WKWebView was improved continuously since 2014 and there is no more major technical differences, at least between WKWebView and a mobile webpage (source [here](http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/03/ios-8-webkit-changes-finally-allow-all-apps-to-have-the-same-performance-as-safari/)). The differences between UIWebView and WKWebView are explainded in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303316/is-wkwebview-designed-as-a-replacement-of-uiwebview).

Keep in mind that [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-interface) forbid some use cases of Webview, like external authentification or purchase :

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Hope it will help !

Comment: I meant UIWebView? What are the differences in design consideration when developing the two (I mean technical differences)?