# iOS How to add cookie to each UIWebView request?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, uiwebview

I need to open URL with Angular in `UIWebView` and I need to send cookie with each `UIWebView` request.

What I tried to do:

I tried to check if request contains cookie. If it does `UIWebView` performs request, if not I create the same request but with cookie and perform it. To substitute requests I used `UIWebViewDelegate`'s method `func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool`. But it works not as I expected, some requests performs without cookies.

My code:

```
final class FieldServiceViewController: UIViewController {

    private var webView = UIWebView()
    private var sessionID = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _ = JSONAPI.getSessionID().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] sessionID in
            self?.sessionID = sessionID
            self?.configureUI()
            let string = "https://someURL"
            let url = URL(string: string)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            self?.webView.loadRequest(request)
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        webView.frame = view.bounds
    }

    private func configureUI() {
        webView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    private func cookedRequest(from: URLRequest) -> URLRequest? {

        let cookiesKey = "Cookie"
        let headers = from.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
        if (headers.contains { $0.0 == cookiesKey }) {
            return nil
        }

        var request = from
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        let cookiesToAdd = "SESSIONID=\(sessionID)"
        request.addValue(cookiesToAdd, forHTTPHeaderField: cookiesKey)
        return request
        }
    }

    extension FieldServiceViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        if let cooked = cookedRequest(from: request) {
            webView.loadRequest(cooked)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

How to add cookie to each UIWebView request?

P.S. I also saved cookie in `HTTPCookieStorage`, but looks like there is no connection between `UIWebView`'s requests and shared storage at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Problem was solved by creating a cookie with specific domain:

```
final class FieldServiceViewController: UIViewController, DLHasHomeTitleView {

    private let fieldServiceEndPoint = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "FIELD_SERVICE_ENDPOINT") as! String

    private var webView = UIWebView()
    private var sessionID = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureUI()

        _ = JSONAPI.getSessionID().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] sessionID in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }

            self.sessionID = sessionID

            let urlString = "https://\(self.fieldServiceEndPoint)"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

            let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
                .name: "JSESSIONID",
                .value: sessionID,
                .path: "/",
                .domain: self.fieldServiceEndPoint])
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie!)

            self.webView.loadRequest(request)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) instead of [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) as UIWebView is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165912/2299040).

> Now about adding the session id to each request made by your Angular
>   project.

Instead of adding the session id by creating new request from delegate method, I would recommend adding a [request interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) at Angular level this will give you more control over each request made by your Angular project.

Register the interceptor via an **anonymous factory**

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       config.headers['SESSIONID'] = 'Your Session id here';
    },

    'response': function(response) {

    }
  };
});
```

> Now how you can use this.

You can convert the above code to Swift String and when you have your session id and the Angular Project is loaded you can execute this by wkwebview's  [evaluatejavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=swift) method.

e.g.

```
var sessionId = "you id"
        var s="\n" +
        " $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {\n" +
        " return {\n" +
        " \'request\': function(config) {\n" +
        " config.headers[\'SESSIONID\'] = \'\(sessionId)\';\n" +
        " },\n" +
        " \n" +
        " \'response\': function(response) {\n" +
        " \n" +
        " }\n" +
        " };\n" +
        " });"

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(s, completionHandler: {(message,error) in
            print(error ?? "No Error")
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution, but now I get white screen. The page doesn't load at all

Comment: webView.evaluateJavaScript() returns error:
`Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=2, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $httpProvider, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=15, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=about:blank, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}`

Comment: @BadCodeDeveloper you need to execute this after the Angular Project has been loaded

Answer (score 3):

You can change your code to this:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if request.allHTTPHeaderFields?["SESSIONID"] == nil {
       var request: URLRequest = request
       request.allHTTPHeaderFields?["SESSIONID"] = "your_session_id"
       webView.loadRequest(request)
       return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**UPDATE**

As I see, best way to solve your problem is to intercept your requests with `URLProtocol`.
Create next class:

```
class MyURLProtocol: URLProtocol, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    static let protocolKey = "MyURLProtocolKey"

    private var connection: NSURLConnection?

    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        if let isCustom = URLProtocol.property(forKey: MyURLProtocol.protocolKey, in: request) as? Bool{
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        //You can add headers here
        var request = request
        print("request: \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? " ")")
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields?["SESSION_ID"] = "your_session_id"
        return request
    }

    override class func requestIsCacheEquivalent(_ a: URLRequest, to b: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        return super.requestIsCacheEquivalent(a, to: b)
    }

    override func startLoading() {
        let newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = self.request as! NSMutableURLRequest
        URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: MyURLProtocol.protocolKey, in: newRequest)
        self.connection = NSURLConnection(request: newRequest as URLRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    }

    override func stopLoading() {
        self.connection?.cancel()
        self.connection = nil
    }

    //MARK: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods
    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive response: URLResponse) {
        self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .notAllowed)
    }

    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive data: Data) {
         self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data as Data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(_ connection: NSURLConnection) {
        self.client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
    }

    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
    }
}
```

Now in your `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    URLProtocol.registerClass(MyURLProtocol.self)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it works the same. Some requests performs without cookies

Comment: @BadCodeDeveloper could you check what is a difference btw requests with cookies and without?

Comment: Requests performed by Angular are without cookies. That's all the difference I can see