# Auth0 login stop working when I started using WKWebViewOnly

Tags: ios, cordova, authentication, auth0

as mentioned in the title, Auth0 login in my Cordova application stopped working after I started using WKWebViewOnly. I was forced to stop using UIWebView directly by [Apple’s opinion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132174). I solved this with [this tutorial from Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html).

The login does not take place and a token handover error is displayed.
Has anyone met this and would have any advice and tips for solutions? My login in Cordova is more or less similar to the official one in the example for Cordova from Auth0.

Edit: I found out that even this official sample from Auth0 does not work for Cordova - I am attaching the log:

```
2020-07-31 19:48:53.938995+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 is starting.
2020-07-31 19:48:53.939201+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-07-31 19:48:53.970982+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file
2020-07-31 19:48:54.541889+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Auth0 Example
2020-07-31 19:48:54.542087+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-07-31 19:48:54.542240+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-07-31 19:48:54.570681+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-07-31 19:48:54.570812+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-07-31 19:48:54.572759+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2020-07-31 19:48:54.572921+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] Using WKWebView
2020-07-31 19:48:54.573465+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][console] 0.123024ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.573783+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.142932ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.575008+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.067996ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.575266+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.088096ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.575525+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.127912ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.575702+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] CDVPlugin class CDVUIInAppBrowser (pluginName: uiinappbrowser) does not exist.
2020-07-31 19:48:54.575828+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][uiinappbrowser] 0.157952ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.576153+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][wkinappbrowser] 0.177026ms
2020-07-31 19:48:54.576275+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 3.027081ms
2020-07-31 19:48:55.064209+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2020-07-31 19:48:59.653016+0200 Auth0 Example[50002:688943] {"original":{"crossDomain":true,"method":"POST","url":"https://erstgrain.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token"},"code":null,"description":null,"name":"Error"}
```

Thanks to everyone for the advice and tips.

Comment: Paste your config.xml

Comment: Could your issue be because WKWebView stores cookies differently as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24982211/6617215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engin plugin and start using [Ionic Web View for Cordova](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview).

Next, in the Applications section, add the following text to the Allowed Origins (CORS) field:

```
file://*, localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080, file:///*, ionic://localhost, http://localhost:8100, http://localhost
```

I hope this helps someone.